# How to insert text to these Ball object in paper.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, paperjs

I want to add some single-word text to each ball in this (http://paperjs.org/examples/candy-crash/) project.

For example, python is written on one ball and javascript is written on another ball.

I don't know is it possible to do this? and if possible how to do this.

Below is the paper script code which generates it.

```
function Ball(r, p, v) {
    this.radius = r;
    this.point = p;
    this.vector = v;
    this.maxVec = 15;
    this.numSegment = Math.floor(r / 3 + 2);
    this.boundOffset = [];
    this.boundOffsetBuff = [];
    this.sidePoints = [];
    

    this.path = new Path({
        fillColor: {
            hue: Math.random() * 360,
            saturation: 1,
            brightness: 1
        },
        blendMode: 'lighter',
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
        this.boundOffset.push(this.radius);
        this.boundOffsetBuff.push(this.radius);
        this.path.add(new Point());
        this.sidePoints.push(new Point({
            angle: 360 / this.numSegment * i,
            length: 1
        }));
    }
}

Ball.prototype = {
    iterate: function() {
        this.checkBorders();
        if (this.vector.length > this.maxVec)
            this.vector.length = this.maxVec;
        this.point += this.vector;
        this.updateShape();
    },

    checkBorders: function() {
        var size = view.size;
        if (this.point.x < -this.radius)
            this.point.x = size.width + this.radius;
        if (this.point.x > size.width + this.radius)
            this.point.x = -this.radius;
        if (this.point.y < -this.radius)
            this.point.y = size.height + this.radius;
        if (this.point.y > size.height + this.radius)
            this.point.y = -this.radius;
    },

    updateShape: function() {
        var segments = this.path.segments;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i ++)
            segments[i].point = this.getSidePoint(i);

        this.path.smooth();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i ++) {
            if (this.boundOffset[i] < this.radius / 4)
                this.boundOffset[i] = this.radius / 4;
            var next = (i + 1) % this.numSegment;
            var prev = (i > 0) ? i - 1 : this.numSegment - 1;
            var offset = this.boundOffset[i];
            offset += (this.radius - offset) / 15;
            offset += ((this.boundOffset[next] + this.boundOffset[prev]) / 2 - offset) / 3;
            this.boundOffsetBuff[i] = this.boundOffset[i] = offset;
        }
    },

    react: function(b) {
        var dist = this.point.getDistance(b.point);
        if (dist < this.radius + b.radius && dist != 0) {
            var overlap = this.radius + b.radius - dist;
            var direc = (this.point - b.point).normalize(overlap * 0.015);
            this.vector += direc;
            b.vector -= direc;

            this.calcBounds(b);
            b.calcBounds(this);
            this.updateBounds();
            b.updateBounds();
        }
    },

    getBoundOffset: function(b) {
        var diff = this.point - b;
        var angle = (diff.angle + 180) % 360;
        return this.boundOffset[Math.floor(angle / 360 * this.boundOffset.length)];
    },

    calcBounds: function(b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i ++) {
            var tp = this.getSidePoint(i);
            var bLen = b.getBoundOffset(tp);
            var td = tp.getDistance(b.point);
            if (td < bLen) {
                this.boundOffsetBuff[i] -= (bLen  - td) / 2;
            }
        }
    },

    getSidePoint: function(index) {
        return this.point + this.sidePoints[index] * this.boundOffset[index];
    },

    updateBounds: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i ++)
            this.boundOffset[i] = this.boundOffsetBuff[i];
    }
};

//--------------------- main ---------------------

var balls = [];
var numBalls = 18;
for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    var position = Point.random() * view.size;
    var vector = new Point({
        angle: 360 * Math.random(),
        length: Math.random() * 10
    });
    var radius = Math.random() * 60 + 60;
    balls.push(new Ball(radius, position, vector));
}

function onFrame() {
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < balls.length; j++) {
            balls[i].react(balls[j]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0, l = balls.length; i < l; i++) {
        balls[i].iterate();
    }
}
```

I am new to it. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by adding a `PointText` item over the path to display the ball name.
Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.
And here is the updated code (added lines are commented).

```js
function Ball(r, p, v, name) {
    this.radius = r;
    this.point = p;
    this.vector = v;
    this.maxVec = 15;
    this.numSegment = Math.floor(r / 3 + 2);
    this.boundOffset = [];
    this.boundOffsetBuff = [];
    this.sidePoints = [];


    this.path = new Path({
        fillColor: {
            hue: Math.random() * 360,
            saturation: 1,
            brightness: 1
        },
        blendMode: 'lighter'
    });

    // Create a text item to display the name.
    this.text = new PointText({
        content: name,
        justification: 'center'
    });


    for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
        this.boundOffset.push(this.radius);
        this.boundOffsetBuff.push(this.radius);
        this.path.add(new Point());
        this.sidePoints.push(new Point({
            angle: 360 / this.numSegment * i,
            length: 1
        }));
    }
}

Ball.prototype = {
    iterate: function() {
        this.checkBorders();
        if (this.vector.length > this.maxVec) {
            this.vector.length = this.maxVec;
        }
        this.point += this.vector;
        this.updateShape();
    },

    checkBorders: function() {
        var size = view.size;
        if (this.point.x < -this.radius) {
            this.point.x = size.width + this.radius;
        }
        if (this.point.x > size.width + this.radius) {
            this.point.x = -this.radius;
        }
        if (this.point.y < -this.radius) {
            this.point.y = size.height + this.radius;
        }
        if (this.point.y > size.height + this.radius) {
            this.point.y = -this.radius;
        }
    },

    updateShape: function() {
        var segments = this.path.segments;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
            segments[i].point = this.getSidePoint(i);
        }

        this.path.smooth();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
            if (this.boundOffset[i] < this.radius / 4) {
                this.boundOffset[i] = this.radius / 4;
            }
            var next = (i + 1) % this.numSegment;
            var prev = (i > 0) ? i - 1 : this.numSegment - 1;
            var offset = this.boundOffset[i];
            offset += (this.radius - offset) / 15;
            offset += ((this.boundOffset[next] + this.boundOffset[prev]) / 2 - offset) / 3;
            this.boundOffsetBuff[i] = this.boundOffset[i] = offset;
        }

        // Place the text at the center of the path.
        this.text.position = this.path.position;
    },

    react: function(b) {
        var dist = this.point.getDistance(b.point);
        if (dist < this.radius + b.radius && dist != 0) {
            var overlap = this.radius + b.radius - dist;
            var direc = (this.point - b.point).normalize(overlap * 0.015);
            this.vector += direc;
            b.vector -= direc;

            this.calcBounds(b);
            b.calcBounds(this);
            this.updateBounds();
            b.updateBounds();
        }
    },

    getBoundOffset: function(b) {
        var diff = this.point - b;
        var angle = (diff.angle + 180) % 360;
        return this.boundOffset[Math.floor(angle / 360 * this.boundOffset.length)];
    },

    calcBounds: function(b) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
            var tp = this.getSidePoint(i);
            var bLen = b.getBoundOffset(tp);
            var td = tp.getDistance(b.point);
            if (td < bLen) {
                this.boundOffsetBuff[i] -= (bLen - td) / 2;
            }
        }
    },

    getSidePoint: function(index) {
        return this.point + this.sidePoints[index] * this.boundOffset[index];
    },

    updateBounds: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment; i++) {
            this.boundOffset[i] = this.boundOffsetBuff[i];
        }
    }
};

//--------------------- main ---------------------

var balls = [];
var numBalls = 18;
for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
    var position = Point.random() * view.size;
    var vector = new Point({
        angle: 360 * Math.random(),
        length: Math.random() * 10
    });
    var radius = Math.random() * 60 + 60;
    balls.push(new Ball(radius, position, vector, 'Ball ' + i + 1));
}

function onFrame() {
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < balls.length; j++) {
            balls[i].react(balls[j]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0, l = balls.length; i < l; i++) {
        balls[i].iterate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, This is what I was looking for. Thank You So Much...